# SQL Server LIKE comparison

Tags: sql, comparison, sql-like

I have two tables in my database that I want to compare.

View image for better viewing: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdn6kej6l9rk0lb/CapturaVendorClient.PNG

I want to compare if my knowledge_base.description contains any vendor.name values ​​and store them in another field of knowledge base called vendor_name (is still not created)

Example of knowledge_base.description: Client: Deutsche Bank
Vendor: Santa Fe - Singapore
Invoice: 025516

Example of vendor.name: Santa Fe

I tried using like and other tutorials on the net but did not work for me.

Something so you can compare like this:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE knowledge_base.descrition LIKE vendor.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create the crosswalk between Vendor and Knowledge_Base first, then inner join them so you can pull in the vendor name:

```
SELECT KB.*, VN.VDescription
FROM Knowledge_Base KB

INNER JOIN 
   (
   select V.[Name] as VDescription, K.Description as KDescription
   FROM vendor, knowledge_base 
   where knowledge_base.description like '%' + vendor.name + '%'
   ) VN
ON KB.Description = VN.KDescription
```

Comment: Ohh thanks, this will help me a lot. 
This is only part of the process that I have to do. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

For like to actually work you need to include wildcards.  A % means match anything at this point.

So, as an example, Santa Fe is not like Santa Fe - Singapore because then the like is looking for an exact match.  Santa Fe% does match Santa Fe - Singapore because the like operator looks for Santa Fe followed by anything.

Try:

```
select * 
where vendor.name like '%' + knowledge_base.descrition + '%'
```